# Change IVT of 8086 / 88

Tags: assembly, x86-16, interrupt-handling, emu8086

as you know when interrupt happened ,8086 get code type of interrupt and multiple it in 4,then Check it in IVT.

know I wanna change IVT in 8086,I'm using emu8086.

What should I do for it?

Comment: And I would like to write a program. How should I do it?

Comment: @MikeNakis I don't have any idea about doing it and how to do it.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you need to be more specific. A lot more specific. It would be nice to explain, for example, in precisely what way you want to change the IVT.  Do you want to replace the entire IVT with different contents? Do you want to replace a single interrupt vector with another? Are you talking about a specific interrupt or must it be parametrizable? Do you have a specific interrupt handler or must that be parametrizable too? If specific, then show us some of the code you already have. If parametrizable, then show an empty function that you would like us to fill-in.

Comment: And if this is homework, please tag it as homework.

Comment: @MikeNakis no,It's for my own knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already know this:
IVT is in address: 0000:0000
As you say, offset of each vector is calculated by multilying interrupt number by 4.
If you want to change a value of single vector, then:

1. disable interrupts (cli)
2. Store old value of the vector if needed.
3. write offset and segment of your interrupt handler to the vector.
4. enable  interrupts (sti)